# Request Failure in AppSync Using @https Directive with Ports Other Than 80

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I've created a GraphQL API definition using Amplify, and I've defined a resolver with the **@https** directive as shown in the schema below:

**Definition**

```
 type Query {
      GetTipoAtividadesSite(limit: Int!): String! @http(url: "http://myapi.net:9012/route" ,headers: [
        {key:"Content-Type", value:"application/json"},
        {key:"KeyServer", value:"{...}"},
        {key:"KeyClient", value:"{...}"},
        {key:"Authorization", value:"{...}"}
      ], method: GET) 
    }
```

However, when testing the API using Postman or an external request, the API responds correctly even when accessed on port 9012. However, when I use the same configuration within AWS, specifically with port 9012, the request fails. Strangely, when I configure the API to use the default port 80, it works fine within AWS. Is there any configuration in Amplify or AppSync that prevents the use of other ports?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using AWS API Gateway to create a proxy, and utilize the API Gateway link!